# Inserting this timestamp into MySQL timestamp column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a series of data that I need to insert into a MySQL table using PHP (Codeigniter).

**Problem:** One of the data is a timestamp that looks like `06/01/12 01:43 PM`. However when I insert it into MySQL timestamp column, it becomes `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How can I format the original format so I can insert it correctly into the timestamp col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to perform the transformation via PHP, it's quite straightforward:

```
$oldFormat = "06/01/12 01:43 PM";
$newFormat = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($oldFormat));
```

[strtotime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[date docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can us MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('06/01/12 01:43 PM', '%m/%d/%y %r'))
```